# How to get same storage path for running android and fast boot?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I try to make updater for my custom rom.

there is code wihch i use to flash updates

```
private void flashRom() throws IOException {


        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        os.write("mkdir -p /cache/recovery/\n".getBytes());
        os.write("echo 'boot-recovery' >/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
        os.write("reboot recovery\n".getBytes());


        os.flush();
    }
```

And generaly it works good. My problemm occurs on some devices where `/sdcard/` is refered to `/mnt/media/` while `getExternalStorageDir()` returns `/storage/emulated/0/..` for same device and i save my files with download manager to
        `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("rom", "update.zip");`
Where I have to save downloaded update or how i can ensure that `getExternalStorageDir()` (or more apporiate method) will return same path as `/sdcard/` in fastboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TWRP recovery instead of CWN and it recognize path properly